# Toggle a class using waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

```
 var $foo = $("#foo");

 $foo.waypoint(function(){
    $(this).addClass("blue").removeClass("red");  
     $.notify(this.id + 'hit');
 },{offset:'25%'});

 $foo.waypoint(function(){
     $(this).addClass("red").removeClass("blue");      
 },{offset:'24%'});

 $foo.waypoint(function(){
     $(this).addClass("blue").removeClass("red");       
 },{offset:'74%'});

 $foo.waypoint(function(){
     $(this).addClass("red").removeClass("blue");      
 },{offset:'75%'});


 <div id="foo" class="blue">
  First Panel
 </div>
```

For a start the class in question fails to toggle. Moreover, `$.notify(this.id)` returns undefined for me?

`$.notify(this.element.id)` IS defined.

Is this something to do with the nature of chaining methods in the waypoint API? If so, how do I overcome it?

Solution:

```
$('#foo').waypoint(  
 function(direction) {
        $('#foo').toggleClass('fadeInLeft');
}, { offset: '50%'}); // toggle at 50% from top viewport
$('#foo').waypoint(  
 function(direction) {
        $('#foo').toggleClass('fadeInLeft');
}, { offset: '-400'}); // toggle again a further 400px down
```

Answer (score 1):

just use the **toggleclass** method http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: It turns out you were onto something there Jan. +1, thanks

Comment: I got into a mess with offsets. I needed animation x% when scrolling down with a `toggleClass` when say I've scrolled down y pixels past the element.

Answer (score 0):

Your original problem was that you used `$(this)`, when you needed to use `$(this.element)`.

Comment: Indeed, but the API docs point to this, so is a little confusing

Comment: Do they? Can you show me a link in the API docs that uses `$(this)`? If there is it's a bug in the docs.

Comment: @cookie That link makes no reference to `$(this)`.

Comment: `notify(this.id + ' hit') !== $(this)`. Your right. My bad